# Mysql - most recent record that was created over N days after the record before it

Tags: mysql

I don't know if this is possible or not, but here's what I'm looking for

I need the current date if the last record created is more than N days old OR the created_at of the first record created over N days after the created_at date of the first record created before it

So, like, if there exist 2 records that have creation dates with a difference greater than N days and no other records created between those two dates, give me the created_at of the most recently created of those records unless the most recent created_at of all records is greater than N days ago, in which case give today's date instead

so given this table and N = 5

```
+----+-------------+
|id  |created_at   |
+----+-------------+
|9   |1 day ago    |
|8   |2 days ago   |
|7   |3 days ago   |
|6   |4 days ago   |
|5   |5 days ago   | < not this date
|4   |6 days ago   | < get this date
|3   |12 days ago  | < not this date
|2   |13 days ago  | < not this date
|1   |20 days ago  |
+----+-------------+
```

I need to get `6 days ago` but not `13 days ago` or `5 days ago`, and if the records looked like this

```
+----+-------------+
|id  |created_at   |
+----+-------------+
|5   |11 day ago   | < not this date, instead today's date
|4   |12 days ago  |
|3   |20 days ago  |
|2   |21 days ago  |
|1   |30 days ago  |
+----+-------------+
```

I need today's date

Comment: is `created_at` a date or literally "11 days ago"?

Comment: it's a date, i just figured that X days ago was easier to read in an example

Comment: If the dates are 1,2,5,6,7,15 days ago you want 15 days ago, because the gap has to be more than N days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a query that calculates the gap between adjacent dates:

```
SELECT created_at, DATEDIFF(@prevdate, created_at) AS diff, @prevdate := created_at
FROM (SELECT created_at
      FROM yourTable
      WHERE created_at <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @N DAY)
      ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS x,
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevdate := NULL) as vars
```

Then add a filter for rows where `diff` is more than `N`, and select the most recent of these

```
SELECT MAX(created_at) AS selected_date
FROM (SELECT created_at, DATEDIFF(@prevdate, created_at) AS diff, @prevdate := created_at
      FROM (SELECT created_at
            FROM yourTable
            WHERE created_at <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @N DAY)
            ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS x
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevdate := NULL) as vars) AS z
WHERE diff > @N;
```

Finally, to get the current date if the most recent date is more than `N` days ago, you can join with another query that gets the most recent date, and use `IF()`.

```
SELECT IF (latest_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @N DAY), CURDATE(), MAX(created_at)) AS selected_date
FROM (SELECT created_at, DATEDIFF(@prevdate, created_at) AS diff, @prevdate := created_at
    FROM (SELECT created_at
          FROM yourTable
          WHERE created_at <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @N DAY)
          ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS x
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevdate := NULL) as vars) AS z
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(created_at) AS latest_date FROM yourTable) AS y
WHERE diff > @N;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3856d5/13)

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for, wont it just return the created_at of the first record newer than the most recent record over N days old?

Comment: That was what you asked for, but it looks like you've changed the question since I posted.

Comment: sorry, my first pass at the example wasn't detailed enough

Comment: Could you update the question to explain it more clearly? You changed the example, but not the text.

Comment: I think I've made it clearer...or more confusing, not really sure what the right words are to describe what I'm thinking

Comment: It was returning the created_at for the record after the one I was looking for so I had to change `SELECT created_at, DATEDIFF(@prevdate, created_at) AS diff, @prevdate := created_at` to `SELECT created_at, @prevdate as fetch_prevdate, DATEDIFF(@prevdate, created_at) AS diff, @prevdate := created_at` and `SELECT MAX(created_at)` to `SELECT MAX(fetch_prevdate)` but otherwise it was exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: That's so hard to read without formatting that I can't tell what the difference is. But don't my sqlfiddle demos return the correct rows?

Comment: No, the fiddle was returning `November, 08 2016 00:00:00` instead of `November, 14 2016 00:00:00`. The modifications I made were pretty much just adding a column with the value of `@prevdate` before it was reassigned later down the query and pulling that column using the outer query instead of `created`

Comment: I must have misread, I thought you wanted the older date from the pair with the 5-day gap, now I see it's the newer date.

Comment: You should post your query as the solution, not accept mine since I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I went with

```
SELECT IF (latest_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @N DAY), CURDATE(), MAX(fetch_prevdate)) AS selected_date
FROM (SELECT created_at, @prevdate as fetch_prevdate, DATEDIFF(@prevdate, created_at) AS diff, @prevdate := created_at
      FROM (SELECT created_at
            FROM yourTable
            WHERE created_at <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @N DAY)
            ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS x
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevdate := NULL) as vars) AS z
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(created_at) AS latest_date FROM yourTable) AS y
WHERE diff > @N;
```

Barmar's answer was like 99% of what I needed but I had to add a field to the date difference subquery to store the `@prevdate` value before it was reassigned further in the select and get the `MAX` of that instead of the `created_at` field